# How to query a dictionary property in a LINQ expression using Entity Framework in .NET 7.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-7.0

I am trying to query a dictionary property of a related entity using Entity Framework in .NET 7.0. I have two table, "Positions" and "Localizations".

In my table Positions there is a field named "TitleId" who is related to the table "Localizations". In the table Localization there is an ID and a field "Values" with a JSON inside, like this:
{"de": "Beispiel auf Deutsch", "fr": "Exemple en français", "en" : "Example in English"}

Now I want to do a search at the level of the Positions table to find out if a term is present in the Title, it doesn't matter on which language.

Here is the code I tried:

```
 var positions = _dataContext.Positions
            .Include(p => p.Title)
            .Where(p => p.Title.Values.ContainsValue(query))
            .AsAsyncEnumerable();
```

But I have the following error:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Position>()\r\n    .LeftJoin(\r\n        inner: DbSet<Localization>(), \r\n        outerKeySelector: p => EF.Property<ulong?>(p, \"TitleId\"), \r\n        innerKeySelector: l => EF.Property<ulong?>(l, \"Id\"), \r\n        resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Position, Localization>(\r\n            Outer = o, \r\n            Inner = i\r\n        ))\r\n    .Where(p => p.Inner.Values.ContainsValue(__query_0))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>.ContainsValue' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

The entity classes are the following:
For the table Positions I have a class Position with this field:

```
public Localization Title { get; set;}
```

For the table Localizations I have a class Localization like this:

```
public ulong Id { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; } = new();
```

I'm using .Net 7.0 and EntityFramework 6.4.4

Comment: How do you store the dictionary? You'll have to provide a conversion for the query to database engine-specific SQL, like `JSONVALUE()`.

Comment: _"I'm using ... **EntityFramework 6.4.4**"_ -  you are using "classic" EF from .NET Framework?

Comment: Persisting json is fine in a database but if you want to filter or join on this then it is better to store it using a 3rd normal form schema instead of a json value in a varchar/nvarchar field.

Comment: @CodeCaster the dictionary is stored as a JSON in the DB.

Comment: @GuruStron i'm using entityFramework from this: https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/wiki

Comment: @Igor I can't change the structure of the DB. But it shouldn't be a problem if it's JSON because in the end all I want is to find if a value X exists in the Values field which is just a string.

Comment: I understand it's JSON, I mean how is the mapping set up? Can EF read and/or write the JSON? The rest of my comment still applies.

Comment: And no, JSON is not "just a string". A _value_ could be "de", while you're looking for the _key_.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes you are right with the is not "just a string". 
And yes it can read and write JSON. in the EntityTypeConfiguration in the Configure Method I have this line builder.Property(e => e.Values).HasJsonConversion();

Comment: You have 2 options I can think of that would not require a schema change and not require extensive coding. 1. If the number of records in the Title table is relatively small just retrieve all of them and filter in memory. 2. Write raw sql query to filter the json and execute it via EF.

Comment: @Igor There is no way to do this with linq with something like I tried ? The problem is the Localization table can be potentially get quite large. And I just wanted to use entity framework and avoid writing raw SQL querie because the database used behind can be MySQL, SQLite, Postgres, etc.

Comment: @Igor Unfortunately .JsonContains doesn't exist on my version of Entity Framework. I switched to the Core version (7.0.5) and it still doesn't exist.

Comment: Shoot, that looks like it was specific to Npsql. Sorry about that.

Comment: For the moment the only solution I have found is to recover the whole table including the other tables. But it's not very efficient...